# “You realize” at end of sentence

Tags: punctuation, word-order, clauses

“This is why you’re here you realize” or “This is why you’re here,you realize.”

I realize that “you realize” could be fronted and resolve this issue. But I’m trying to figure out what part of grammar “you realize” is. It is ellipsis? It seems like a tag statement but lacks an auxiliary verb. It reads as a dependent clause that is missing “…this, right?”.

In any case, I’m trying to figure out why the original sentence looks wrong without a comma.

Comment: Questions about punctuation are usually about *style* and any answer is therefore a matter of opinion. But your question seems to be asking two very different things – one about the punctuation (which would be off-topic as primarily opinion-based) and the other about the description of the second clause. I recommend you [edit] your post to focus on the second element, and explain what research you've done. See also [ask]. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You realize** is emphatic. Not only does it require a comma, it requires a question mark (unless it is purely rhetorical.)

“This is why you’re here, you realize?”

Fronted, we have

1. “[Do] you realize *[that]* this is why you’re here?” (Here that operates as a conjunction and introduces a content clause, i.e. it tells you what you should have realized.)

And not fronted:

2. “This is why you’re here... You do realize that?” (Here "that" is a pronoun. The referent is "What I have just said.")

Answer (score 0):

This use is definitely rhetorical. But I think I was overthinking it and it’s just a fronted adverbial instead of an aside or parenthetical statement.

Based on [this](https://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/commas_after_a_sentence_introduction.htm)

[image: an example of the sentence construction in question from twitter]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your authoritative source is a tweet?

Comment: What information in the link supports your answer (in case of link rot)?  It doesn't look like the source of the image, which does show usage (helpful) but does not explain it.